# How to unit test WCF ServiceHost.Faulted event

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing

Lets say I have the following classes (removing exception handling, etc):

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = ..., ConcurrencyMode = ..., etc)]
public class MyService : IMyService  
{
    ServiceReferenceMethodsHere....
}

public class HostStartup : IHostStartup
{
    private ServiceHost _myHost;

    public ServiceHost myHost
    {
       get { return _myHost; }
       set { _myHost= value; }
    }

    public void StartService(IMyService instance)
    {
        _myHost = new ServiceHost(instance);
    }

    public void StopService()
    }
        _myHost.Close();
    {
}
```

Now, subscribe to the `ServiceHost.Faulted` event:

```
// Note: Interfaces are registered via unity container and dependency injection.
// Unity bootstrapper class not shown. 
public class TestHost : ITestHost
{
    private IHostStartup _hostStartup;
    private IMyService _myService

    public TestHost(IHostStartup hostStartup, IMyService myService)
    {
        _hostStartup = hostStartup;
        _myService = myService;
        hostStartup.StartService(_myService);
        hostStartup.myHost.Faulted += HandleHostFault;
    }

    private void HandleHostFault(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HandleFaultHere.....
    }
}
```

Okay, great, now I have code to handle a `ServiceHost.Faulted` event. (Of course I have not shown all the other WCF guts that really make my service work...)

**My question is**, how to unit test my private HandleHostFault method without cheating and setting it to public (we all want to do that at times).
In other words, is it possible to raise `ServiceHost.Faulted` event in unit testing environment?

I prefer to use NSubstitute for my unit testing.  I have tried the following:

```
private IHostStartup _hostStartup;
private IMyService _myService;
private TestHost _testHost;

public void MyTestInitialize()
{
    _hostStartup = Substitute.For<IHostStartup>();
    _myService = Substitute.For<IMyService>();
    _hostStartup.When(x => x.StartService(Arg.Any<IMyService>())).Do(x =>
                 {
                    _hostStartup.myHost = Substitute.For<ServiceHost>();
                 });
    _testHost  = new TestHost(_hostStartup, _myService);
}

public void HandleHostFault_InitializeHost_ServiceHostStatusOpen()
{
     // Arrange

     // Act
     hostStartup.myHost.Faulted += Raise.Event();


     // Assert
}
```

`hostStartup.myHost.Faulted += Raise.Event()` does not raise the faulted event.

**Any ideas how to raise this servicehost.faulted event?  Is it possible?**

** UPDATE **

I decided not to test ServiceHost communication object directly. I decided it was "not testable using NSubstitute". I now handle the ServiceHost.Faulted event from my HostStartup class.

```
public class HostStartup : IHostStartup
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnHostFault;

    public ServiceHost MyHost { get; private set; }

    public void StartService(IMyService instance)
    {
        MyHost = new ServiceHost(instance);
        MyHost.Faulted += HandleFault;
    }

    public void StopService()
    }
        _myHost.Close();
    {

    private void InvokeOnServiceHostFault(EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = OnHostFault;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, eventArgs);
    }

    private void HandleFault(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        InvokeOnServiceHostFault(eventArgs);
    }
}

// Note: Interfaces are registered via unity container and dependency injection.
// Unity bootstrapper class not shown. 
public class TestHost : ITestHost
{
    private IHostStartup _hostStartup;
    private IMyService _myService

    public TestHost(IHostStartup hostStartup, IMyService myService)
    {
        _hostStartup = hostStartup;
        _myService = myService;
        hostStartup.StartService(_myService);
        hostStartup.OnHostFault += HandleHostFault;
    }

    private void HandleHostFault(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HandleFaultHere.....
    }
}
```

and finally the unit test action works great:

```
public void HandleHostFault_InitializeHost_ServiceHostStatusOpen()
{
     // Arrange

     // Act
     hostStartup.OnHostFault += Raise.Event();  // works great!! :)


     // Assert
}
```

Comment: Testing an event being thrown from another process(service) is not unit testing.  This is integration testing.  If you want to test the fault method - you can abstract it and gain access to it by creating an internal method to access the "implementation of the fault handling" method and use the InternalsVisibleTo option to give your Test Class access to your code.

Comment: Do you realize that your HostStartup class only works if MyService is marked as InstanceContextMode.Single? If you want Unity to inject the service instance, you are better off implementing IInstanceProvider.

Comment: My particular service only requires InstanceContextMode.Single. Thanks for the tip on using IInstanceProvider ErnieL!  tsells, thanks for your tip regarding use of InternalsVisibleTo option. Yes, I was on a bad path using integration testing (thanks again!). I decided to declare the ServiceHost communication object as "not testable". I now handle the ServiceHost.Faulted event in my HostStartup class. The HostStartup class now provides a public OnFault event for subscription by my TestHost class. Now, the faulted event can be raised from HostStartup using NSubstitute. See updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can unit test any private member of class using PrivateObject class.
See below link for explanation and example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546207.aspx